# Which part of the system is a typical bottleneck with R and Shiny server on a Linux instance?

Tags: r, shiny, ubuntu-server

So which part of the system is a typical bottle neck on R/Shiny server? I understand that answer to my question depends on an app being deployed, but for the sake of the argument let's say I am talking about [hello world Shiny app](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/example-01-hello.html)

Approximately how many users of this app would a 4 core 8gb virtual machine support? And what would be the bottleneck,the RAM or the CPU?

Comment: It's really impossible to answer, it is dependent on the app. If you have an app with 3GB of data but only simple visualizations, the RAM. If you have an app with 500MB of data but a join between two tables every second, the CPU.

Comment: If you use open source version, keep in mind that there's only one R process per connection. So when you have multiple users and each use a function that runs say 10secs, then it won't be done in parallel thread but rather user1 waits 10secs, user2 20secs, user3 30secs, etc.

Comment: Would using Microsoft's free R change that?

Comment: Shiny server is available only for linux machines

Comment: Yeah, but Microsoft R is also available for linux machines